# React Native - iterating an array using map() to update this.state.variable

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to iterate through an array and create `<View><Text>this item</Text><View>` for each item in the array, add them together, and setState to a variable in order to update a list on the page.

I'm able to iterate through the array and create simple text entries on the page for each item in the array. I'm also able to create one `<View><Text>this item</Text></View>` and update the page. However, when I try to put both together (format the text AND combine them all together), I get [object][Object] for each item.

```
    var schedule = getUserSchedule(this.state.apiToken).then(resp => {
        if(resp.status == 'success'){
                if(resp.schedule[0].length>0)
                {
                    console.log('Got user scheduling entries: ', resp.schedule[0]);
                    resp.schedule[0].map((data) => {
                        var currentSchedule = this.state.userSchedule;
                        var thisEntry = <View style={{width : Metrics.screenWidth - 80 , height : 35,flexDirection : 'row', alignItems : 'center', justifyContent : 'center'}}><Text style={{color : 'white', fontSize : 16}}> + data.key + </Text></View>;
                        //var thisEntry = data.key;  (THIS WORKS)
                        var newSchedule = currentSchedule + thisEntry;
                        this.setState({
                              userSchedule:newSchedule
                            });
                    }); 
                } else {
                    Alert.alert('Success','null');
                }
        } else {
                Alert.alert('Error',resp.error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can't concatenate two objects that way.  Try Rendering the currentSchedule where you would usually and then add the "thisEntry" under the currentSchedule.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting these results from an API and I don't know how many there'll be. I need to list them on the page.

Currently, I just have that section of the page with:
<Text>{this.state.userSchedule}</Text>

And this function is meant to update this.state.userSchedule to be the list of objects that should be shown

What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: The mapping should not be a stateful object because, although it is bound to a state, it is for displaying. What should be stateful is the results from the API. It looks like you're trying to repeat the current schedule for every result, so simply returning the currentSchedule rendered above the mapped "thisEntry" should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
const mappedSchedule = resp.schedule[0].map(data => <View key={data.key}><Text>{data.key}</Text></View>)
this.setState({ userSchedule: mappedSchedule })
```

This will create a map of your schedules. Which you can put inside the state.

A full version in case you'd like to modify some values inside the map would look like this: (In some way or form)

```
const mappedSchedule = resp.schedule[0].map((data) => { 
    let value= <View key={data.key}><Text>{data.key}</Text></View>;

    // Do some stuff

    return value;
  }
)
this.setState({ userSchedule: mappedSchedule })
```

Answer (score 0):

- As pointed out in the comments you can't add a component to an array using `array + component`.
- It's probably also not a good idea to update state inside the map causing rerenders on every iteration, rather compute all the components and update the state at the end.
- `.map` is used to update the values in the array not for its side effects. If using side effects should probably use `forEach`, but here .map is fine but move the changes to afterwards.

Try something along the lines of:

```
if (resp.status == 'success') {
  if (resp.schedule[0].length > 0) {
    console.log('Got user scheduling entries: ', resp.schedule[0]);
    var newSchedule = resp.schedule[0].map(data => {
      return(
      <View
        style={{
          width: Metrics.screenWidth - 80,
          height: 35,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center'
        }}
      >
       <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 16 }}>{data.key}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  });

  this.setState({
    userSchedule: [...this.state.currentSchedule, newSchedule]
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will want to do this in two steps.

1) Fetch the data and save the data to your component's state.

2) In your components render method, map over the data to create your ui.

```
    export default class UserSchedule extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            userScedule: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const token = this.state.apiToken;
        this.fetchUserSchedule(token);
    }

    /**
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    fetchUserSchedule(apiToken) {
        return getUserSchedule(apiToken).then(res => {
            if (res.status == 'success') {
                if (res.schedule[0].length > 0) {
                    const userSchedule = res.schedule[0];
                    this.setState({userSchedule});
                    return
                } else {
                    Alert.alert('Success', 'null');
                }
            } else {
                Alert.alert('Error', resp.error);
            }
            this.setState({userSchedule: null});
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {userSchedule} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {userSchedule &&
                userSchedule.map(schedule => (
                    <View
                        key={schedule.id}
                        style={{
                            width: Metrics.screenWidth - 80,
                            height: 35,
                            flexDirection: 'row',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 16}}> + data.key + </Text>
                    </View>
                ))
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```